# Smallint stayed null after executing update SQL statement in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

The DB was `Sybase`. I executed update SQL statement like

```
UPDATE table_name SET smallint_col = 0, 
datetime_col = CONVERT(datetime, '1999-09-09') WHERE some_col = 'sth';
```

to set a null `smallint` attribute into a nonnull value.

I checked the update result with select statement right after the update statement via JDBC.

The attribute stayed null. Only the datetime attribute have been updated to intended value.

Also, here are what I have tried:

1. Set the target value to a nonnull value larger than 0. Still same result as above.
2. Added `and smallint_col IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause. This time the update of both attributes failed.

Is there anything wrong with my update SQL statement?

What could be a possible reason for this?

Is there any possibility that the update of a certain attribute of a table is restricted?

Btw, I can only access to the DB with JDBC and I am trying to avoid talking to the DBA.

Comment: This looks like impossible. 
UPDATE table_name SET smallint_col = 0, 
datetime_col = CONVERT(datetime, '1999-09-09') WHERE some_col = 'sth';

Did you try this SQL command in any ASE client?  
After execution,  it will return message of "affected count". If it's 0, then there will be no rows updated.

You can check it first.
Another one is that,  could you paste the complete DDL of your table?

Basically, I don't think this could be a problem.

Comment: Does the where clause match something in the first place?

Comment: Sounds like there is a trigger or something similar which always forces the value of this column to be NULL. Can you rule this out?

Comment: There should be something else cause that column not changed.  Just wait for the reporter's response.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? what does `select count(*) from table_name where some_col = 'sth'` return (making sure to use the *same exact* where clause from the UPDATE statement)? are there any rules or triggers on the table? have you tried another client (eg, `isql` if using ASE, IQ or SQLAnywhere)? why not speak to the DBA?

Comment: There is only one record matched the where condition of the update and select statement. The datetime attribute was updated to a timestamp like '2022-5-15 00:00:00.000' of execution right after update. Pretty sure nothing wrong with the where clause. Which Sybase product and its version are unknown.

Comment: The affected count was always 1. When 'and smallint_col IS NULL' was added to WHERE clause, it was 0.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked below whole SQL statements under Sybase ASE database, there is no problem on the update operation.
If you are using JDBC call, you can get the return count of the update SQL execution. to check the affected count.

```
create table table_name (id int not null, smallint_col smallint null, 

datetime_col datetime, some_col varchar(32) null)
go

insert into table_name values(1, null, '2020-05-05', 'sth')
go

select * from table_name
go

UPDATE table_name SET smallint_col = 0, 
datetime_col = CONVERT(datetime, '1999-09-09') WHERE some_col = 'sth'
go

select * from table_name
go
```

Please double check your table definition.  Is it the same as the above?

Comment: Yes, the definition is similar to what I read in the document I was given.